# How can I export a resource that has been depleted

Tags: tropico-5

I am playing the waterborne campaign and to finish the mission I need to export 3000 uranium, but I have depleted my uranium deposit. What can I do to finish the mission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luckily you can export resources that have been imported. Set one of your trade routes to import uranium. If a trade route isn't possible there are buildings you can construct to increase the available trade routes (Lighthouse, Nuclear Submarine), or you can perform delegate missions from an embassy.